# cleos wallet create, command not working

Tags: wallet

When I want to create a wallet in EOS, I get this error:

```
$ cleos wallet list
Wallets
[]
$ cleos wallet create
Either indicate a file using "--file" or pass "--to-console"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Damian, It's better to copy and paste from your terminal than to post images of code/terminal. Image links may not be maintained, often are difficult to read & don't allow for text selection.

Comment: If the any of the answers below solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Either indicate a file using "--file" or pass "--to-console"**

You need to specify the location to write password output to:

`$ cleos wallet create --to-console`

`$ cleos wallet create -n <wallet-name> --to-console`

See the dev [documentation](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-wallet):

> Options
>
> -n, --name TEXT - The name of the new wallet  -f, --file TEXT - Name
>   of file to write wallet password output to.  (Must be set, unless
>   "--to-console" is passed  --to-console - Print password to console
>
> Usage
>
> Shell
>
> $ ./cleos wallet create --to-console
>
> $ ./cleos wallet create -n second-wallet --to-console
>
> $ ./cleos wallet create --name my-new-wallet --file my-new-wallet.txt
>
> $ ./cleos wallet create --to-console
>
> $ ./cleos wallet create -n second-wallet --to-console
>
> $ ./cleos wallet create --name my-new-wallet --file my-new-wallet.txt

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you just need to use one between the following commands, in your command line:

```
  cleos wallet create --to-console

  cleos wallet create --file test.txt
```

1. to print the password of your wallet to the console;
2. to save the password of your wallet in a specific file.

Please, note that running this command, you create an empty waller, and you need to keep note of the “PASSWORD” provided, to access the wallet in the future.

Moreover, I use to specify also the name - that is 12 char long - of the wallet with the option `-n`:

```
cleos wallet create -n randaccountx
```